# What to select for a bounty reason if the answers are wrong?

Tags: discussion, bounties, bounty-remarks

When I choose to put a bounty on a question, it asks me why.  I get the choice of:

- Authoritative reference needed
  Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.
- Canonical answer required
  The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.
- Current answers are outdated
  The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
- Draw attention
  This question has not received enough attention.
- Improve details
  The current answers do not contain enough detail.
- Reward existing answer
  One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

**What if the current answers are just wrong?**  They're answering the wrong question, or just factually incorrect?  The closest I can see is "improve details", but shouldn't there be a "need a correct answer" option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the answers are wrong, just use a "Draw Attention" reason. In your bounty message you can then state that the current answers are inaccurate (perhaps briefly detailing how so) and that you are looking for a correct answer.

Comment: I would say that "Outdated" works well, too. But really, the added text is the important part ;)

Comment: @tohecz If the answers were never correct to begin with (as I read the OP's post) then "outdated" would not be correct. But of course if they were correct but no longer are, you are correct.