# Bounties - how to categorize the reason

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

So I have started my first bounty - joy joy joy. But doing so, I had to decide why I'm putting the bounty, and I hade to choose between "Authoritative reference needed" and "Canonical answer required".
Now I just want a working answer, credible sources are nice, but not the reason, so I selected the second, but I'm not sure that it really is "widely applicable to a large audience". (Or is it that applicable?)

- So What should I check?
- Do you think it's worth adding a "I just want an answer" option (with better wording)?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421136/hijacking-the-realtime-clock-in-linux) is the question.

The options presented to me where:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185778/meaning-of-canonical-answer-required-bounty-category

Comment: Uh oh - "additonal"? **Typo bug!**

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh What?

Comment: @Martin michael just found a typo in the "Reward existing answer" description.

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh yep, will you start a bug report?

Comment: sounds like you just want **Draw attention to question**

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210869/223030

Comment: Happy I helped somehow.. :)

Comment: Is that screenshot just taken? To me the dialogue is entirely different. No red border, close icon on the other side and no spelling mistake. It is causing some confusion on @michaelb958'saSleigh's question!

Comment: No. While looking for "how to tag a bounty" I found another question with this pic, and it had exact wording. So I just linked to it instead of taking a new one.

Comment: Ah that explains it then! Fixed already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally both of those reasons are for questions which *already have answers*.

You'd start an authoritative reference bounty to try and get users to stop providing "general" answers and provide one that has reference and more specific details to back it up (usually for a question that gets a lot of *different* answers that don't necessarily agree with each other).

You'd start a canonical answer bounty on a question that has several answers with are all correct in some way, and you need a single answer that combines them all together to make one definitive answer.

For you, not having *any* answers yet - you're looking for the "draw attention to question" bounty reason. You just want an answer, and you need some extra attention on your question to get one.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find a way to change my decision to "Draw attention to the question". Is it possible?

Comment: No. You can't modify the message once the bounty has started.