# This typo is exemplary and worthy of additonal attention

Tags: bug, status-norepro, spelling, bounty-dialog

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210861/223030) brought to my attention a typo in the bounty dialog:

[image]

Um, yeah, someone missed an `i`. There's also a `.` there that looks out of place.

Comment: Like half the people who try to ping me... :D

Comment: What do you mean @Mystical?

Comment: YAY FOR TYPO BOG!

Comment: shouldn't be I not i, after all, i is not a word in the English language.... oh wait, you are talking about something else.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman Literally just noticed that.

Comment: Additonal.. Isn't that where you are trying to add to the tone of the writing? I think this might be [tag:by-desine].

Comment: Did anyone also notice that most of the other bounty reasons not in bold don't end in periods?

Comment: @hichris123 Good catch; question updated.

Comment: @Mysticial Woah... wait... I *just* realized that you have another `i` in your name :O :O :O ***I've been lied to all my life***

Comment: AHAHA, I pwned another victim! One of these days, I'm gonna get rid of that "i" just to troll everybody... :P:P:P

Comment: I guess I'm going crazy, where are you able to reproduce this? [This is what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pOIzj.png)

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh seeing as I'm not able to reproduce this either, did you confirm this typo still existed, or did you just open a question based on a screen shot?

Comment: Not able to repro this either.

Comment: @NickCraver - Turns out the screenshot that sparked this request [was recycled from an older question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210861/bounties-how-to-categorize-the-reason#comment676877_210861)

Comment: *\*facepalm\** This is what happens when you rush into things, people.

Comment: @Nick [I take the blame](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210861/bounties-how-to-categorize-the-reason?noredirect=1#comment676819_210861) here, should have checked it myself before suggesting to submit bug report! `@`michael: +1 as compensation. :)